# telnet connection refused with IPv6 address

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6

I am trying to use telnet (I know ssh is preferable than telnet but I must need to use telnet here) with IPv6 address.

```
telnet 2001:db8::b84c:f5f3:741f:710

telnet: can't connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

this is my /etc/xinetd.d/telnet file contains,

```
# default: on
# description: The telnet server serves telnet sessions; it uses
# unencrypted username/password pairs for authentication.
service telnet
{
disable = no
Flags = REUSE
socket_type = stream
wait = no
user = root
server = /usr/sbin/in.telnetd
log_on_failure += USERID
}
```

Can anyone suggest me what I am missing?

Comment: you restart inetd ?

Comment: I did **service xinetd start** but no use for IPv6. I am able to telnet to IPv4 address.

Comment: can you `telnet ::1` ? or telnet to default local adress (the one that start with fe80: ) ?

Comment: **telnet ::1
telnet: can't connect to remote host: Connection refused**

Comment: ** telnet fe80::21f:29ff:fe03:8b9d
telnet: can't connect to remote host: Invalid argument **

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xinetd requires IPv6 to be manually enabled:

```
service telnet
{
    flags = REUSE IPv6
    ...
}
```